# Pandas - Efficiently concat rows based on group and column values

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

Suppose we have a pandas dataframe with structure:

`Id  | number |seq|
a   | 1      | X |
a   | 3      | Z |
b   | 1      | P |
b   | 6      | G |
b   | 5      | C |`

And the desired result is a dataframe which looks like:

`Id  |new_seq|
a   | XZ    |
b   | PCG   |`

That is, the `new_seq` column is `seq` grouped by `Id`, and follows the order as indicated by `number` column.

What are the options to efficiently implement this operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `groupby` and `apply` `join`:

```
print (df.sort_values(['Id', 'number']))
  Id  number seq
0  a       1   X
1  a       3   Z
2  b       1   P
4  b       5   C
3  b       6   G

df = df.sort_values(['Id', 'number'])
       .groupby('Id', sort=False).seq
       .apply(''.join)
       .reset_index(name='new_seq')

print (df)
  Id new_seq
0  a      XZ
1  b     PCG
```